# Stored procedure to check if table exists

Tags: sql, sql-server

I haven't being programming in a while and I am stuck on a problem. I am building a small application that you can select one of the 32 counties of Ireland from.

In my database called `BlackCorsetDatabase`, I want to use only stored procedures.

I want to check to see if the table is connected before I try to write to the database first.

This is the code that I have written so far:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CheckTableCountyExists]
    (@TableExists BIT)
AS
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * 
               FROM BlackCorsetDatabase 
               WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'County')
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Table Exists'
        @TableExists = 1
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        Print 'Table does not exists' 
        @TableExists = 0
    END

    RETURN @@TableExists = TableExists
Go
```

What I would like is the output either 1 or 0, so that I can check the result in C#

Comment: Why not just `SELECT @TableExists = 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE . . `? And remember to set the default value for `@TableExists` which is `0`.

Comment: Don't use `RETURN` either for this; you should be using an `OUTPUT` parameter. Also, why would the table not exist here? I *thought* you might be checking for a table based on it's name, but you're not; so why wouldn't it exist at one point and then not later? If you need to it to be part of your design create it at the start; even if that table is empty.

Comment: You are reinventing the wheel, use this instead: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/object-id-transact-sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if a table exists in multiple ways -- for instance, using metadata table or by attempting to access it.

In either case, you will want to use dynamic SQL.

Also, I strongly recommend returning values from a stored procedure using *OUTPUT* parameters, not *RETURN*.  If you want *RETURN* you probably want a stored function.

I like Sami's approach of passing in the names of the components you are looking for.  Here is a version that should work:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.CheckTableCountyExists (
    @DatabaseName SysName,
    @SchemaName SysName,
    @TableName SysName,
    @TableExists BIT = 0 OUTPUT
) AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

    SET @sql = '
SELET @TableExists =
          (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1
                             FROM @DatabaseName.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t
                             WHERE t.TABLE_SCHEMA = @SchemaName AND
                                   t.TABLE_NAME = @TableName
                            )
                THEN 1 ELSE 0
           END)';

    SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql, '@DatabaseName', QUOTENAME(@DatabaseName));

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql,
                       N'@SchemaName sysname, @TableName sysname, @TableExists BIT',
                       @SchemaName=@SchemaName, @TableName=@TableName, @TableExists=@TableExists;
END;
```

Then you call it as:

```
DECLARE @isExists BIT = 0;

EXEC dbo.CheckTableExists N'BlackCorsetDatabase', 
                          N'dbo', 
                          N'County', 
                          @isExists OUTPUT;

SELECT @isExists;
```

The above will fail, though, if the *database* does not exist.  You can fix this with a `TRY`/`CATCH`.  A generic method is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.CheckTableCountyExists (
    @DatabaseName SysName,
    @SchemaName SysName,
    @TableName SysName,
    @TableExists BIT = 0 OUTPUT
) AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

    SET @sql = '
SELET @TableExists =
          (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1
                             FROM @DatabaseName.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t
                             WHERE t.TABLE_SCHEMA = @SchemaName AND
                                   t.TABLE_NAME = @TableName
                            )
                THEN 1 ELSE 0
           END)';

    SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql, '@DatabaseName', QUOTENAME(@DatabaseName));
    BEGIN TRY
        EXEC sp_executesql @sql,
                       N'@SchemaName sysname, @TableName sysname, @TableExists BIT',

@SchemaName=@SchemaName, 
@TableName=@TableName, 
@TableExists=@TableExists;
     END TRY
     BEGIN CATCH
         -- on any error, assume table does not exist
         SET @TableExists = 0
     END CATCH;
END;
```

Note:  You could be more specific about the error.  However, it is hard to imagine a situation where the code works but you get an error in the dynamic SQL *and* want to return "1".

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d6b1118059e483e0729480688f9ac2d8) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks Guys for the help.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to all this code, and also don't use `RETURN` to return a value, it's for checking if the `SP` success or fail.

Your `SP` can be like

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CheckTableCountyExists]
(
  @DatabaseName SysName,
  @SchemaName SysName,
  @TableName SysName,
  @TableExists BIT = 0 OUTPUT
)
AS
  SELECT @TableExists = 1
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
  WHERE TABLE_CATALOG = @DatabaseName
        AND
        TABLE_SCHEMA = @SchemaName
        AND
        TABLE_NAME = @TableName;
Go
```

Then you can use it as

```
DECLARE @MyVar BIT = 0;

EXEC [dbo].[CheckTableCountyExists] N'MyDatabaseName, 
                                    N'MySchemaName', 
                                    N'MyTableName', 
                                    @MyVar;

SELECT @MyVar;
```

In [visual-studio](/questions/tagged/visual-studio) you can check the output variable `@TableExists` if it returns `0` (not exists) or `1` (exists).

Comment: `@DatabaseName` won't work as you expect here. Without dynamic SQL, the query will be run in the context of the database  the SP exists in. Therefore you would always get a value of `0` if you try to check the existence of a table in a different database.